# Create Hangout session with unique link

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I'm working to create a hangout app. where initiator can create a hangout session with unique link and invite others user (called attendees) by giving that unique link. so when an attendee click that link he can attend only that hangout session.

I've created an app. with basic XML file provided by Google, but can't figure out how to create unique link for each hangout session. Is there any functions in Hangout API? as far as I've read API documentation I don't found such function. Can anybody suggest me how to do it?

Please help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This YouTube video discusses how to do what you want: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4

The general procedure will be for the initiator to create a hangout using a link on your website and, as part of creating it, starting up a hangout app. This app sends the URL for the hangout back to your website where it can be sent to the attendees.

Comment: Is this link will be user specific only? because there can be more than hangout session at a time and all should be different and only specific to their hangout session only..

Comment: In the method described in the video, the initial link that initiates the hangout creates a new hangout (and thus a new and unique link). So multiple ones can be opened, depending on your management of them, of course.

Comment: When I initiate a new hangout, can I do so with a list of people pre-invited. I mean, if I have 2 gmail ids with me, when I create a new hangout I need them to be automatically invited to the hangout. Is this possible?

Comment: New questions should be asked as new questions.

Comment: I had asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010875/starting-a-hangout-with-a-list-of-users-invited. Since there were no responses, I tried my luck here.

Comment: I don't want to watch a video, please give the whole answer in text.

Comment: It is something of a moot point, anyway. The API it references hasn't existed for several years now.